# Search Results: urls of BDC items suddendly start with bdc3://

Tags: search, external-content-type, custom-action

I have a scope defined that targets an external content type (exposed through a BDC service). All was working fine until yesterday when the number of results doubled and half the urls start with the bdc3:// protocol; the other half are the original results that have always been there.  I need to get rid of these extra links.

So far I tried the following which did not work:

1. Went into the ETC's BDC Connectivity service for the ETC and recreated the profile page (note that I already had a custom action set for defining the url I want).
2. In the search service, I did an index reset
3. I did a full recrawl of the content source for my ECT.

How do I get rid of these?

Comment: does this help? http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fastsharepoint/thread/a3178882-d2c5-41bc-8abe-7ba45b7d64d0/

Answer (score 2):

MOVED FROM COMMENT BY @chris-m (marked as CW)

Solution:
Turns out the issue was caused by the configuration of the scope rule, ContentSource = NameOfContentSource (which we had incorrectly named after the ECT).

The name was misleading because a content source represents an external data source not an individual ECT.

Over time we added several ECTs that all used the same external data source (& only one of them used profile pages w/ an alternate action, hence the bcd3:// links).

To resolve the issue we changed the scope rule to: CustomPropertyName = ContentTypeName after having mapped the crawled property 'EntityName' to CustomPropertyName.